# Google Adwords/Ads scraper with php

Tags: php, web-scraping, google-ads-api, bing

Is there some script for free for scraping google ads / bing ads with php by given keyword, so I can take a look over my competitors for this keyword?

Comment: I am looking for the same thing, not sure this is a right place to ask

Comment: here is the script that you are looking for http://www.alreadycoded.com/seo-tools/google-search-ads-scraper.html